# Threading inside of a thread does not working

Tags: python, multithreading

Hey I want to make a two different process in the same code. But when my second thread is gonna be working. It gives me an error

I am trying to make the drone flight and also make to process image in drone camera. test function opens the camera and process the image. drone_ucur function flights the drone.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "deneme1.py", line 341, in mustafa
    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 285, in init_node
    rospy.core.register_signals() # add handlers for SIGINT/etc...
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/core.py", line 623, in register_signals
    _signalChain[signal.SIGTERM] = signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, _ros_signal)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

I don't know how signal is working in thread. But tutorials about threading make it. But I could not figure out how.

Here is my simple code,

```
def test():
   
    
    ic = image_converter()

    rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
    try:
        
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")
        
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def drone_ucur():
    git(5)
    
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target = test, args=[])
    thread1.start()    
    

thread = threading.Thread(target = drone_ucur,args=[]) 
thread.start()
'''
```

Comment: Please and the full error traceback to the question!

Comment: [You might require to `init_node` out from a `threading.Thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45569380/15981043). Try initializing it in your main (i.e. before `thread.start()`)